# Compilation of Procedures vs Function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures

In some sites I have read that procedures are complied only once and called multiple times without compiling. But on the other hand, a function is compiled every time it is called.

But another site claims that both are precompiled once. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1):

In practice every query executed in SQL Server is compiled and the execution plan is cached. This is valid for stored procedures, user defined functions and other. An exception is for example if [OPTION (RECOMPILE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/recompile-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017) is specified.

Here is a quote from the [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/user-defined-functions?view=sql-server-2017#Benefits):

> Similar to stored procedures, Transact-SQL user-defined functions reduce the compilation cost of Transact-SQL code by caching the plans and reusing them for repeated executions.